# How to use javascript output on image

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>(function(e,d) {
    //Ringba.com phone number tracking
    var ringba_com_tag="JS3a38bffffb544d0f8245sssss0df9686";
    var _sc = d.getElementsByTagName('script'), _s = _sc[_sc.length - 1];
    e._rgba = e._rgba || { q: [] }; e._rgba.q.push({ tag: ringba_com_tag, script: _s });
    if (!(e._rgba.loading = !!e._rgba.loading)) {
        var sc = d.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.async = true;
        sc.src = '//js.callcdn.com/js_v2/min/ringba.com.js';
        var s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, s);
        e._rgba.loading = true;
    }
   })(window,document);</script>
```

I have the above code it gives me a output with a 10 digits phone number randomly. I want to use the output on the top right side corner of the image. I am not good at this kind of stuff but I got this requirement now. Also is there any way that I can store this java script output and I can use the output whereever I want on the page?

I got the answer from their support.here is the code it might help to others `4

```js
<span class="phNumber"></span>
<script>
function GotNumber(number, tagId, firstTime)
{
 if(firstTime)
        window.pnumber = number;
}
(function(e,d) {
        //Ringba.com phone number tracking
        var ringba_com_tag="JS3a38bffffb544d0f824sssss9ddd9686";
        var _sc = d.getElementsByTagName('script'), _s = _sc[_sc.length - 1];
        e._rgba = e._rgba || { q: [] }; e._rgba.q.push({ tag: ringba_com_tag, cb: GotNumber, numberClass: "phNumber", render: false, script: _s });
        if (!(e._rgba.loading = !!e._rgba.loading)) {
            var sc = d.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.async = true;
            sc.src = '//js.callcdn.com/js_v2/min/ringba.com.js';
            var s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, s);
            e._rgba.loading = true;
        }
   })(window,document);
</script>
```

The only thing left is I want to use that out put on the image on the right top corner.

Comment: This is just a minified script that inserts another script from a CDN. The script does not generate phone numbers?

Comment: Yes. but the final output will be phone number. Its a script given by a cloud phone system. I am not sure how the back-end works but the output is a phone number. That I have tested today. I have modified the js links to hide my data.

Comment: We can't really help you with the placement of something that is generated and inserted by a script we know nothing about ?

Comment: I can send the code personally because it contains the number if some one call to that number I will charged.

Comment: where happens the actual return of the phone number? Something like `var phoneNumber = niftyFunctionThatReturnsNumber()` or does the function deploy the number to the window. Add a `console.log( heresMyNumber )`. In addition it would be helpful to see the rendered markup of the image and wrappers if there are any as well. You must help us to help you - you know...

Comment: I have updated my code its a working code but I just disabled all the calls. You can see the script demo at http://104.131.130.186/test.html if I turn on the phone number , on this page it will show a number.

Comment: Yes, I just spoke with then they said its outdated hence they removed it just. I am sorry. I dont have much resources now.

Comment: Don't worry! Actually the function that returns the number is quite irrelevant. If you say it returns a number ok. So from this point one can say we have `var number = someWhateverFunction();` (its enough, its better!). You ask for: "I want to use the output on the top right side corner of the image." So again: #1 where is the output (this is what I tried to explain above)? #2 where is the image?

Comment: @Axel - look at the example the OP posted above. There is no `var number = ...` it's just a minfied script that inserts a script tag into a DIV, and this script tag runs an external script that lives on a CDN, and that script, the one on the CDN, inserts the number. The OP doesn't have anything that generates a number at all.

Comment: Can u post ur email address I will email the working link where you can see the number so that you can examine the code. or email me at pgems.co.cc@gmail.com

Comment: @adeneo thats why I'm asked "does the function deploy the number to the window"? Where does this number live :)

Comment: @Axel - and I can help with explaining that, I think? The number lives on a server, more specifically a CDN, right [**here**](http://js.callcdn.com/js_v2/min/ringba.com.js). The OP's code inserts that script into a DIV, and the script on the CDN then inserts the number right above the script tag, into the DOM of the OP's page. The number doesn't exist on the OP's page, other than being dynamically inserted into a DIV by that script.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help I got the solutions from their support now I just want to use it on the image.

Comment: @adeneo got it now - thx

Comment: "The only thing left is I want to use that out put on the image on the right top corner." So again: **which image** - I cannot see an image in your code?!?! is `<span class="phNumber"></span>` the place where after the script is executed the number is inserted like `<span class="phNumber">1234567890</span>`???

Comment: Everything fine now? Or do you still need advice?

Comment: Its fine now. I am all set.